# how to add button in android studio?

Tags: android, android-button

**Whenever i click on submit button the app crashes,i am a beginner and  followed a youtube video to this**

*here is the code*

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
    int sum = num1 + num2;
    t1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
}
```

Comment: Any error logs? How do you set the `onButtonClick` method to the button? And what does your layout xml look like?

Answer (score 1):

To Display a button add a button in XML File.

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button_id"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button" />
```

For `OnClick` action , set a `OnClickListener` on the button object in the corresponding activity.

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             setContentView(R.layout.layout_id);

             final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
             EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);//Make Sure that this is EditText or TextView
             EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
             TextView t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
             int num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
             int num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
             int sum = num1 + num2;
             button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     t1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
                 }
             });
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a clickable button (on Chipmunk)

1. Name a function (ie. buttonClick) and put it in the onClick attribute
   [image]
2. Go to the code, point mouse cursor to the red buttonClick, a popup will ask for "More actions"
   [image]
3. Click "More actions" then "Create 'buttonClick(View)' in 'MainActivity'"
   [image]
4. The correct code will be automatically added as I underline in red. (tested in Kotlin).

[image]

5. Try to write to the easiest TextView first

> ```
> fun buttonClick(view: View) {
>   findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView1).text="test"
> }
> ```

where `<TextView>` refers to the tag name of `<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"...` in the xml file, and `textView1` is the value after `@+id/`

Comment: Add button listener always on code, on XML it can give errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58136795/buttons-onclick-force-closes-app-on-android-4-1-device