# Buttons onClick Force closes app on Android 4.1 device

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-button

I have an app with a simple layout with one button. I've tried implementing an onClick using `AppCompatButton` and `AppCompatImageButton`. But when I run it on a Android 4.1 device, when I click on it, my app crashes (Unfortunately, App Has Stopped).

I did the same test on a Android 5.0 device, and it worked. Then tried the same but using `Button` and `ImageButton` instead and it worked on both.

Those Buttons have no Style nor Theme were applied. Just bare Buttons with 30 x 30 dp. Here's the code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/adContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:onClick="btnClick" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set ActionBar to Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }


    public void btnClick(View v) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

For the moment I'm using `ImageButton` but I don't know if that will imply some compatibility issue on some Android version (I'm supporting API 16+).

Thanks.

**EDIT:** That's what LogCat shows when using `AppCompatButton`:

```
10-03 17:01:36.706 1313-1313/com.example.testappcompatbutton D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-03 17:01:36.706 1313-1313/com.example.testappcompatbutton W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62ba288)

    --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
10-03 17:01:36.734 1313-1313/com.example.testappcompatbutton E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method btnClick(View) in the activity class androidx.appcompat.widget.TintContextWrapper for onClick handler on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btn'
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3578)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: btnClick [class android.view.View]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3571)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Seems like it can't find the onClick method.

Comment: Please show your stacktrace of the crash

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks, added. But why did the "android 5.0" and "android 4.1 kitkat" tags got removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never actually seen this before, but it looks like a combination of two things:

- On pre-lollipop devices, `AppCompatButton` uses a `TintContextWrapper` as the context of the button view
- The `android:onClick` attribute uses reflection to find the method to execute, looking inside the view's context

Together, this means that the system is looking for `btnClick()` in the wrong place, and so the app crashes.

You can solve this by setting the click listener through code rather than by using the `android:onClick` attribute. In your MainActivity's `onCreate()` method:

```
View button = findViewById(R.id.btn);
button.setOnClickListener(v -> btnClick(v));
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Although I got a "Lambda expressions are not supported at language level '7'". But just changing `v->btnClick(v)` with: `new View.OnClickListener{...}` did the thing.

Comment: Ah, yes, if you're using language level 7 then you have to use an anonymous inner class. There should be no problem using language level 8, though. NBD either way.