# Toast not appearing on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make a toast appear when I click a button. I have already set the button's on click to be the 'cli function'. However when I press the button nothing appears. Could you please help me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: where do you using method of cli? Can you share all code please.

Comment: You are not using your cli(View vi) method anywhere. You have to call it first, you can do so from onCreate().

Comment: Presumably `cli` is set as the onClick method for a button in the XML? If so, you should include that. And if that's the case, are you clicking the button and the toast doesn't show?

Comment: yes i am clicking the button and the toast doesn't show

Comment: When you click on it, is this on a real device or an emulator? (not just in Android Studio layout preview, right?) Also, please add code/xml as text, not as images (and add the full `activity_main.xml` file)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `onClick` on XML, as it's buggy and may not work on all versions:

[Buttons onClick Force closes app on Android 4.1 device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58136795/11880323)

Better do it in code:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
       // code here
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In xml,make sure you declared `onClick`  in your `Button` attribute

```
android:onClick="cli"
```

Also, in `onCreate`, declare your `Button` id

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Comment: I have already declared on click in my button attribute

Comment: you haven't initialized your button id in onCreate.

Comment: Getting the view in `onCreate` does not "initialize the button ID" -`findViewById` just retrieves an existing view from the current layout by ID.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `onClick` on XML.

Use `OnClickListeners`. Here is the code:

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
       cli(v);
   } 
});
```

The above code will help you with detecting clicks on the button. Prefer not using `android:onClick` in XML.